# Detecting changes to a property

Tags: c#, properties

I am trying to create a class that transparently loads and saves a class to a form of persistent storage.

Currently I am using the pattern:

```
get
{
  return _data;
}
set
{
    //Do change logic
    _data = value;
}
```

This works well for when the _data object is first set, as the set accessor is being called. However, if get is used a reference is returned. Any changes to the data objects properties via this reference are not detected as at no point is the set accessor called.

I would call the persistence logic in the get accessor, but at this stage the changes are yet to be made. I have also considered using a destructor to save all the changes upon termination, but I believe it is bad practise to do blocking operations in a destructor?

Is there a better pattern or methodology that would call the change logic for this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, I would have a "Save" function that does this (on a click or timer or whatever). That way you limit your hits to persistence.

If you *really* want to save on every property change, consider having the affected object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It is usually used for bindings, but you can subscribe to the events just as well! In the event handler you can check the name of the property that was changed and run your save logic.

Comment: I would not call `INotifyPropertyChanged` "usually for WPF", winforms bindings like `BindingSource` listen to it also.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, changed to "used for bindings". Is that more accurate in your eyes?

Comment: I would say that is a much more accurate description. (now if you had been talking about Dependency Properties for triggering changes I would have agreed 100% that it is a WPF only thing)

Comment: This seems like exactly what I needed thank you. Is it ok to use in a generic with " where T : INotifyPropertyChanged", or will this cause boxing?

Normally I would use a save method also, but this is to be integrated with entity framework. The theory is this would transparently handle large data objects in a blob storage, with the associated key being saved to an sql table via entity framework

Comment: @Venatu, I'm not an expert on boxing, but I believe it primarily concerns value types. Shouldn't be an issue here.